# could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, django-rest-framework

Не поднимается база что ли , не могу понять что с ней не так.

could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Django settings

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', 'neighbors'),  # noqa: F405
    'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'neighbors_user'),  # noqa: F405
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),  # noqa: F405
    "HOST": os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', 'db'),  # noqa: F405
    "PORT": int(os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT', 5432)),  # noqa: F405
    }
}
```

.env

```
POSTGRES_USER=neighbors_user
POSTGRES_USER=neighbors_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=neighbors_pass
POSTGRES_DB=neighbors
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data

DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_HOST=db
```

docker-compose

```
db:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: docker/postgis/Dockerfile
image: neighbors_db:latest
restart: always
env_file: .env
volumes:
  - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
ports:
  - "5439:5432"
```

Comment: Ну Вы же устанавливаете `"HOST": os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', 'db')`, что в переводе на русский означает "имя компьютера (DNS либо NetBIOS), на котором расположен сервер БД = 'db'". Это - правильно? если правильно - значит, не работает служба разрешения имён, а если неправильно - то надо поправить. Ещё лучше - указать там не имя, а IP-адрес (который у сервера БД по идее должен быть статическим).

Comment: Удивительно что это работало буквально пару дней назад. а вот уже 2й день эта ошибка. а я по сути ничего не менял( 
А как/где посмотреть этот IP БД?
Заранее спасибо за советы)

Comment: Это IP не БД, это тот IP, который слушает твой Постгресс. Смотри в его настройках, либо в настройках ОС, поверх которой он работает.

Comment: Сложна. не до конца понял, но хоть есть ориентир. 
развернуто это всё в убунту - тоже в докере
В любом случае спасибо )

Comment: Попробуйте рестартануть докер https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448826/2231972

Answer (score -1):

Это происходит, потому что db не является адресом в сети. Попробуйте в качестве аргумента по умолчанию указать 'localhost' или '127.0.0.1'. Вот есть пример в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Как можно тут заметить, ключу PORT соответстует конкретный адрес в сети.

Также в документации есть [информация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/) по подключению Postgis.

Comment: Но это ранее работало и так вот как есть сейчас(
странно(

Comment: В докере, а точнее, в даном случае, в docker-compose имя сервиса автоматически добавляется в dns или hosts, так что нет - этот ответ совсем неправильный. `localhost` это текущий контейнер, а тут postgres запущен в отдельном, так что `localhost` не сработает.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, а пардоньте, не заметил. почему-то мне казалось, что это докер самого проекта с базой внутри.

Comment: Так и есть. я просто только кусок с базой добавил